# If G is a p-group, the number of nonnormal subgroup is a multiple of p?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I want to show that

> If $G$ is a finite $p$-group, then the number of nonnormal subgroups of $G$ is a multiple of $p$.

I think I need to consider a conjugation action. But then?

Comment: Consider the action of $G$ on the set of all its subgroups by conjugation. What are possible lengths of orbits (think about the orbit-stabilizer theorem). What is special about normal subgroups?